# recreate NSManagedObject subclasses when the model changes in the model editor

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I was wondering if there was a way to update the NSMangedObject subclass after you change a property or add a field in the Core Data model editor.  Sometimes I add a field, or realize that I accidentally put integer as the type instead of string, but my NSManagedObject subclass was already created.  So instead of manually going in and adding those fields, I was wondering if there was a way for Xcode to just update the model?  Thanks.

Comment: You should definitely check out [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator). It generates classes from the object model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Others have explained how you can re-create the files, but do notice that the files overwrite the original ones, so if you have made any manual additions (extra methods, for instance) you're going to lose them. A backup can be useful before you write the files out again.

If you do need to add functionality to an `NSManagedObject` subclass, consider using categories in separate files. That way you can tweak your class in the Core Data editor, re-export your files and avoid losing your additional functionality because it is saved in the category files.

Comment: that is ingenious. also, i feel bad for not realizing this a) on my own and b) much sooner. THANKS.

Comment: As @katzenhut says, genius.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to go to file -> new -> file -> core data under iOS -> NSManagedObject subclass and it is self explanatory from there.

You can also check out mogenerator, an open api that helps manage a lot more of core data for you.